# store html code of a JSF page automatically

Tags: java, html, jsf, servlet-filters

I have a JSF (IceFaces 1.8.2) website. I need the following functionality: When a specific JSF page is displayed, I would like to store its HTML code in a database. I tried to use Servlet filters to capture the code (using a HttpResponseWrapper object as it is written on the SUN webbage and in a lot of tutorials), but the response was always empty. Can somebody help me?

Here is the doFilter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain)
    throws IOException, ServletException {  

    Wrapper responseWrapper = new Wrapper((HttpServletResponse)response);
    chain.doFilter(request, responseWrapper);
    //I just want the output on stdout at the moment...
    System.out.println(responseWrapper.toString());
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.write(responseWrapper.toString()); 
    }
```

And here is the Wrapper:

```
public class Wrapper extends HttpServletResponseWrapper{
    private CharArrayWriter writer;
    public Wrapper(HttpServletResponse response){
        super(response);
        writer = new CharArrayWriter();
}

public PrintWriter getWriter(){
    return (new PrintWriter(writer));
}

public String toString(){
    return writer.toString();
}

public char[] toCharArray(){
    return (writer.toCharArray());
 }
}
```

And the web.xml:

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>foo.myfilter</filter-class>
</filter> 
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>*.iface</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Maybe there's a bug in your code, please post your work to give you better guidance.

Comment: Don't post the code in comments. Edit your question and add the code there. Don't worry about the format, anyone can edit it until you learn the basics of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps JSF sends a redirect, or writes the response using `response.getOutputStream()`? Try setting break points in all methods of `HttpServletResponseWrapper` to discover which methods JSF invokes.

Comment: JSF uses the getOutputStream. I had to create a subclass from ServletOutputStream to make the response readable. Thanks

Comment: you can also activate jsf debugging via ui:debug tag.  it puts a full copy of the page output into the session object.  retrieve with a phase listener or simlar event mechanism and push to db.  be warned that ui:debug will bloat your session objects, so i would only recommend it's use in a low availability or non-production product.